# Pulling values out of angular template reference variables

Tags: angular

I'd like to figure out how tall an element on my page is, and set a spacer div to fit. The "intuitive" thing to do here is use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars).

```
<div class="spacer" [style.height.px]="footer.clientHeight"></div>
<div class="footer" #footer></div>
```

This actually almost works - you can interpolate `{{footer.clientHeight}}` into the DOM correctly, except (a) this value doesn't seem to change when the footer changes height - it just stays as the initial value and (b), relatedly, the system then throws an error of type `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` which is pretty descriptive although doesn't particularly indicate a fix.

So the question is: is there a decent way to do this? The twist here is that my footer div is conditionally rendered with an `ngIf`, which I think is adding to my woes.

I poked at viewChild as well, but that doesn't seem to help a lot - I want an observable that pulls the clientHeight (or some other height measure) out of the element.

Comment: Is the spacer div empty and immediately above the footer?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the DOM exclusively, sometimes you are at its mercy in terms of the sequencing of variables and references being created. Based on your description it looks like your spacer is rendering before the `#footer` reference is available, then once it becomes available its changing the value of `spacer` which has already been checked. I'm guessing when you printed the output of `{{footer.clientHeight}}` it was below the `footer` element? You could try holding off on rendering the `spacer` until the footer has been rendered simply by using `*ngIf`.

```
<div class="spacer" *ngIf="footer" [style.height.px]="footer.clientHeight"></div>
<div class="footer" #footer></div>
```